# How to make a Regex that matches one or more comma-separated numbers?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need to create a regex which will match and group values from strings such as:

```
(fdsa) 12.3,322.3, 213, 332.5
```

and

```
(asdf ASDF) 2.7, 3
```

From each input string I would like to get the following match groups:

- 1st group would be the text inside the parenthesis.
- 2nd/3rd/n-th group would be the floats or ints that follow. There will be a minimum of one number, but there is no upper limit.

So, for example, the first string above should yield the following match elements:

- fdsa
- 12.3
- 322.3
- 213
- 332.5

I'm having troubles with the second part, which is getting one or more match groups for the float/ints. My regex so far is:

```regex
\((.+)\)[ ,]*([0-9]+?[.]?[0-9]*)
```

However this one matches only the words inside brackets and the first float/int. It does not match the rest.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: `\(([^\(\)]+)\)([^,]+)(?:,([^,\n]+))?(?:,([^,\n]+))?(?:,([^,\n]+))?(?:,([^,\n]+))?(?:,([^,\n]+))?$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VnhGWa/1)

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: @Daniel: seriously? What if there are 40 numbers separated with commas? Also, no need to escape parenthesis in a character class and no need to exclude the opening parenthesis.

Comment: Regex probably isn't the right solution.  If you're using python you could just use split() a couple of times.

Comment: Would using a regex that matches a single number, eg `\d+(\.\d+)?`, then finding all those matches work for you?

Comment: This question sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359). While it is very helpful to include what you have already tried, it is sometimes no less helpful to potential answerers to explain why you have tried that approach.